# How to set p margin for a section

Tags: css

Super basic question, I'm new to CSS...

In my stylesheet I've got:

```
  #topheader {
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100px;
        background-color: #D1E6DA;
        font-size: 200%;
}
```

How do I add:

```
p {
    margin: 20px;
}
```

Inside the #topheader (not for the whole page)?

Comment: It's really a super basic question, and amazed of upvotes for such question...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#topheader p{
    margin: 20px;
}
```

see the space between the `#topheader` and the `p` ? it means p inside the topheader.

you need to leave the `#topheader { }` as is, and add another one with the `p` in it as i wrote above.

so you will have the following:

```
#topheader {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #D1E6DA;
    font-size: 200%;
}
#topheader p{
    margin: 20px;
}
```